Is satisfying the Farrell-Jones conjecture a quasi-isometry invariant of a group?
My understanding from these lecture slides is the ($K$-theoretic) Farrell-Jones conjecture for a group $G$ (with coefficients in a ring $R$) states that a certain assembly map is actually a bijection.
We can regard a group as a metric space via the word metric. Then there is a notion of groups $G$ and $H$ being quasi-isometric, which comes up a lot in geometric group theory, since, e.g., many invariants of groups are preserved under quasi-isometry.
My question is: Fix a coefficient ring $R$. If a group $G$ satisfies the Farrell-Jones conjecture and $H$ is quasi-isometric to $G$, does $H$ also satisfy the conjecture?

I believe that this is as open as FJ conjecture itself. (At least in early 2010s it was totally unknown.)

The following paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01704 considers passage to finite index over-groups, which appears still to be a difficult open problem.
